# Starting new activity from a non activity class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I know it's been alot of questions like this, but I didn't find the answer.

**What I have:**

1. A **GridView** + a **ButtonAdapter** class, which also has a **OnClickListener** class to get wich button on the GridView in pressed. (you can see the basic structure here : http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/09/android-creating-a-custom-adapter-for-gridview-buttonadapter/)

**What I need:**

I need to start a new `Activity` from my `OnClickListener` class. As I know I can make it only in my main acitivity class(or other class which extends `Activity`), but this is what I really need.
I know only this structure:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyMain.this, MyNewActivity.class)
startActivity(i);
```

I want to be able to use this structure from my `OnClickListener` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `ButtonAdapter` constructor pass the context of the `Activity` where you build the adapter and then use that `Context` to start the new `Activity`.

**Edit:**
Following that tutorial when you build your adapter you will do something like this:

```
ButtonAdapter adapter = new ButtonAdapter(this);// this is the activity(if you create in an activity the adapter)
```

The `Context` that you get in the constructor of your `ButtonAdapter` you will pass it to your `OnClickListener`:

```
    class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener  
    {  
     private final int position;  
private Context ctx;

     public MyOnClickListener(int position, Context ctx)  
     {  
      this.position = position;  
this.ctx = ctx;
     }  

     public void onClick(View v)  
     {  
      // Preform a function based on the position  
      someFunction(this.position)  
      Intent i = new Intent(MyMain.this, MyNewActivity.class)
ctx.startActivity(i);
     }  
    }
```

and use it like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(position, mContext));
```

Comment: could not find how to pass the context of the Activity, could you please write some example code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have View object in your MyOnClickListener.onClick() you can simply use View.getContext() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) to get the context object and start another activity.